# Problemas com operadores aritméticos em C++

Tags: c++

Estou tentando fazer com que o programa calcule o valor de desconto de um determinado valor inserido pelo usuário;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    float number1, number2, desconto;

    cout << "Digite o valor de compra do seu produto R$ ";
    cin >> number1;

    desconto = number1 * (30 / 100);
    number2 = number1 - desconto;

    cout << "O produto custa R$ " << number2 << " reais com 10% de desconto.";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu estou vendo um problema, mas ajudaria se você descrevesse o que está acontecendo diferente do esperado, e qual a sua dificuldade.

Comment: por exemplo: se eu entrar com o valor de 120 o programa não me retorna o valor correto que seria o desconto de 30%, me retorna os mesmos 120

Comment: Então, os valores `30` e `100` são inteiros, e o resultado da divisão de números inteiros é um inteiro, ou seja, vai ser `0`. Se você quer que o resultado seja `0.3`, deveria fazer `30.0 / 100.0`.

Comment: Valeu mano, era justamente isso, deu muito certo!!!

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo baseado no comentário do usuário user140828.

O problema é que na divisão de 30 por 100 você está usando números inteiros e o valor acaba sendo truncado para zero. Isso acontece porque variáveis de tipo inteiro não podem armazenar números decimais.

Para obter o valor correto basta trocar o tipo do número 30 para `float` (de ponto flutuante):

```
desconto = number1 * (30.0 / 100);
```

Dessa maneira o resultado da operação `30.0 / 100` passa a ser `0.3` e deixa de ser simplesmente `0`.